# How can I use a list in the clause of an sqlQuery in R using RODBC package?

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to use a list of sample sites in a sql query to extract data for those sample sites.  I am using a loop to draw data from several databases and then bind it together as one dataframe.

This works if I list out all the sample sites separately, but I will eventually have over 1000 sample sites and would rather just use a list instead of writing these all separately in the query.

Here is how I have built my sql query:

```
  Query_all <- paste0("
                      SELECT 
                      SAMPLE_POINTS.REF
                      MEASUREMENTS.RESULT
                      
                      FROM
                      SAMPLES INNER JOIN MEASUREMENTS ON SAMPLES.SAMP_ID = 
                      MEASUREMENTS.MEAS_SAMPLE_ID
 
                      WHERE 
                      SAMPLE_POINTS.REF in ('SITE0001','SITE0002');",sep="")
  
  data <- sqlQuery(channel, Query_all, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like the WHERE clause to refer out to a list rather than have to list SITE0001, SITE0002, SITE0003...SITE1000.

Other answers on here don't have the sql query as a separate variable so I am struggling to see how I can change my code based on those answers.  I am new to R and sql and databases generally, and this is code someone else has given me to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two problems:

1. Construct your vector of site strings. (Let's use vectors, not lists, as you shouldn't have any need for a `list` class object here.)
2. Put that in the the string with the rest of the query.

```
## build the site strings
library(stringr)
## I'll use `1:3` to illustrate, you can change my 3 to 1000
sites = paste0("SITE", str_pad(1:3, width = 4, side = "left", pad = "0"))
# make sure they look right
sites
# [1] "SITE0001" "SITE0002" "SITE0003"
site_string = toString(sQuote(sites, q = FALSE))
# this quotes the sites and sticks them together
# as one comma-separated string:
site_string
# [1] "'SITE0001', 'SITE0002', 'SITE0003'"
```

That looks ready to go in a SQL query. Here are 3 ways we could do that. For all 3, I'll start with a (slightly different) starting query:

With base R's `paste`, we can simply stick things together. This works pretty well if you're sticking one piece in a query.

```
# paste method:
qry = "SELECT 
SAMPLE_POINTS.REF
MEASUREMENTS.RESULT

FROM
SAMPLES INNER JOIN MEASUREMENTS ON SAMPLES.SAMP_ID = 
MEASUREMENTS.MEAS_SAMPLE_ID

WHERE 
SAMPLE_POINTS.REF in ("

qry_all = paste(qry, site_string, ");") ## we also paste on the final );
```

`paste` is really common, but for "fill-in-the-blank" sort of stuff, I like `sprintf` better. We use `%s` as a placeholder in the string, and then it replaces that with additional arguments. If you were filling in variables in multiple places in the query, I find this much more readable:

```
# sprintf method:
qry = "SELECT 
SAMPLE_POINTS.REF
MEASUREMENTS.RESULT

FROM
SAMPLES INNER JOIN MEASUREMENTS ON SAMPLES.SAMP_ID = 
MEASUREMENTS.MEAS_SAMPLE_ID

WHERE 
SAMPLE_POINTS.REF in (%s);"

qry_all = sprintf(qry, site_string)
```

Improving on that even more, the `glue` package lets us refer to R objects in the string by name, wrapped in `{}`. This is really nice if you are putting multiple objects in the string, because with `sprintf` you have to make sure you get the order of them right, but here based on name the code is more readable:

```
# the glue method:
library(glue)
qry = "SELECT 
SAMPLE_POINTS.REF
MEASUREMENTS.RESULT

FROM
SAMPLES INNER JOIN MEASUREMENTS ON SAMPLES.SAMP_ID = 
MEASUREMENTS.MEAS_SAMPLE_ID

WHERE 
SAMPLE_POINTS.REF in ({site_string});"

qry_all = glue(qry)
```

All of these methods will generate the same `qry_all` string, which you can pass to `sqlQuery` as usual: `data <- sqlQuery(channel, qry_all, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Also note that if you `print()` these `qry_all` strings in your console, the linebreaks will be printed as `\n`. To interpret the linebreaks, use `cat(qry_all)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, I have gone for the third option and it all works beautifully.  One snag is that I did also have a date from / date to line in the WHERE clause that was as follows: `SAMPLES.SAMPLE_DATE >= to_date ('", FROMDATE ,"', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                      AND SAMPLES.SAMPLE_DATE <= to_date ('", TODATE ,"','dd/mm/yyyy')` but R doesn't seem to like the commas around FROMDATE and TODATE (these are both values that are input at the top of my code).  Any thoughts on how I can include a date boundary in my query?

Comment: Down here in the comments it's hard for me to understand. It seems like you're using a `paste()` style syntax there, whereas if you are going with the `glue` option your base query should include something like `SAMPLES.SAMPLE_DATE >= to_date('{FROMDATE}', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`..., assuming `FROMDATE` is the name of an R object you have containing a string in the dd/mm/yyyy format.